# Can Noahides have a prayer book?

Tags: gentiles, prayer-book, noachide-laws, noahidism, noahide

I heard somewhere that Noahides are not supposed to have a prayer book while others say it's okay. I'm not sure if having a prayer book that isn't the Jewish siddur permissible?

Comment: I don't think this is limited to a prayer book but in regards to establishing religious practices in general. That being said there are prayer books for Noahide that have been made and I think the distinction that allows them is they were not made by Noahide themselves.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Nobody can require you to use a certain book, prayer certain prayers, or bend, or bow, or turn, or wear a special piece of clothing. You also may chose to use any prayer book you want, if you believe it helps you get closer to the Creator. There are Orthodox, Reform, Conservative, Karaite, Reconstructionist, Chabad, Askenazi, Sefardic, Young Israel, and various Noahide prayer books. There are also 150 Psalms and other prayers throughout the Tanak. Our best prayers come from our heart. The Creator wants these the most.

Comment: @Dude do you have the links to which prayer books noahides can use that aren't made by noahides themselves?

Comment: @Simplest this is the only one I'm aware of but there are likely others... https://asknoah.org/books?cat=199

Answer (score 0):

There is a Noahide siddur that was put out under the guidance of Rabbi Yirmeyahu Bindman, Rabbi Michael Katz, [Rabbi Yoel Schwartz](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A5) and Rabbi Yechiel Sitzman.

In the foreword, R. Michael Katz writes:

> Prayer is not specifically commanded to B’nai No’ach but that is only
> because it is the most obvious requirement of man....B'nai No'ach are
> not bound by the formulae created by the Sages for Jews, but they can
> find their own manner in which to express their thanks. It need not
> even be expressed verbally; thinking grateful thoughts while enjoying
> a tasty snack would be adequate for B'nai No'ach... Prayer is required
> of all mankind simply because to not pray to GOD is to insult Him. Not
> praying denies that GOD is the source of all that is good and has the
> power to provide all of our needs. What form should prayer take? Here
> B’nai No’ach are given permission to give full expression to the
> depths of their gratitude. Let them give wings to their thoughts of
> love and reverence and find the words that most speak to their souls.
> It is, however, a sign of the humility of the B’nai No’ach in our
> generation, that they are reluctant to compose their own prayers and,
> instead, they wish to turn to the traditional prayers composed by the
> Sages of old for the Jewish communities. This they can do with the
> proviso that they are careful not to utter any untruths. Thus, they
> must be careful not to imply that they are commanded to do activities
> that only Jews are commanded to do. They must be careful not to refer
> to the Patriarchs as their fathers since, in most cases, they are
> probably not.

The full text of the Noahide siddur they crafted can be downloaded here:

[Service From the Heart: Renewing the Ancient Path of Biblical Prayer and Service](https://www.okbns.org/pdf/Offerrings.pdf)

It would seem that at least according to the aforementioned rabbis, having a Noahide siddur is permitted as long as it does not run afoul of any other theological issues (e.g. speaking untruths, engaging in practices reserved for Jews, etc.).

---

Here is a [link to a responsum in Hebrew by R. Yoel Schwartz](https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=75220&sid=f135be6b7b6d4d0d3b3101c58ee853ff) in which he permits it. Rabbi Elhanan Naftali Prins has a responsum (Shu"T Abhne Derekh vol. 15, no. 9) in which he disagrees with R. Schwartz and prohibits the distribution of a Noahide siddur. Time permitting I will try to summarize next week (unless someone else wants to take a crack at it first).